# How to Import Preferences (.epf) in eclipse via command prompt?

Tags: eclipse, import, preferences

I wanted to run a bat file in which it can **import preferences** from a location (which was exported manually). I searched for the ***command which would import preferences*** but, could not find any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no existing code to do this. You would have to write an Eclipse headless application that does something like this:

```java
IPreferencesService service = Platform.getPreferencesService();

IExportedPreferences prefs = service.readPreferences(file input stream);

// TODO create IPreferenceFilter array to filter what you want

service.applyPreferences(prefs, filter array);
```

See the source of the import preferences page `org.eclipse.ui.internal.wizards.preferences.WizardPreferencesImportPage1` for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Backstory: I was looking for something similar and, a few tabs back, I've stumbled on a "half-an-answer"/alternative solution. Even if the thread is old might still turn in handy ...

In [this page](http://blog.vogella.com/2012/08/07/eclipse-papercut-9-default-preference-settings-via-plugin_customization-ini-type-filter-example/) the author talks about using `-pluginCustomization` parameter inside the `eclipse.ini` file

```
-pluginCustomization
plugin_customization.ini
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse....
```

The `plugin_customization.ini` file is similar to the `*.epf` file, same variables minus the `/instance/` prefix (maybe because this way they are  interpreted/applied at product(eclipse) level and not as per-workspace preferences).