# Pass eclipse preference epf file at eclipse runtime from commad line

Tags: eclipse

I need to pass eclipse preference file (epf file) while invoking eclipse from command line. Is it possible to do so or is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason why you want to pass through it from command line. IMHO there is no direct way.

Refer this post [How to Import Preferences (.epf) in eclipse via command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295198/how-to-import-preferences-epf-in-eclipse-via-command-prompt)

Also

1. When eclipse opens up. You can import all preferences from `File > Import > General > Preferences`. Here you can choose which types of preferences to be imported. See help [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wb.doc.user%2Fhtml%2Fpreferences%2Fpreferences_export.html)
2. You can set preferences via **plugin_customization.ini** [check here](http://blog.vogella.com/2012/08/07/eclipse-papercut-9-default-preference-settings-via-plugin_customization-ini-type-filter-example/). Then call the eclipse instance via command line. See standard command line options [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html)